# How to create util files with uiveri5?

Tags: uiveri5

I have two problems that might be connected:

I need a utils.js file to have some util functions in it to import in different specs.

The other thing is I have the same beforeEachTest function to run before all tests and don't want to copy-paste it in every spec.

How should it be done with uiveri5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIVeri5 is a ordinary nodejs application. Both conf.js and the spec.js files are ordinary modules and so you can require() anything in them. So just create your utils module in a ./utils/utils.js and require it in your ./test.spec.js like: var utils = require('./utils/utils.js');
This way you can import the same util in every spec.js. Or even further, you can enclose the tests in a nodejs package (dir with package.json) and then create one more project that contains you team utils and then import them in the test project like any nodejs package. Of course, no need to publish on a repository, just install with git+ssh link.